# REQUEST: Downhill ski recordings

Tags: request, snow, recording, sport

Hello all,

I'm seeking recordings of Olympic-style downhill skiing. Everything from start & aways, passbys (slow/med/fast) and in & stops. Also, jump impacts.

Anyone have material like this? Willing to barter/trade/beg and steal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a bunch of skiing and snowboarding pass-bys (slightly varying speeds, over an ice patch) recorded with a Sony PCM-D50, but I haven't had time to edit them down from the raws yet. There might also be some jump landings in there, I can't remember at the moment.

I'll investigate when I get home tonight.

Comment: @Shaun, thanks very much. Eager to hear what you've got!

Answer (score 1):

I found some ski recordings, including jumps and stuff. It also comes along with ice and snow textures
http://www.asoundeffect.com/sound-library/snow-and-ice-textures/